# Programatically Update a Module

Tags: 6

Is it possible to programatically update a module in Drupal 6? In otherwords, run an update as if running from update.php. I assume so. I looked at update.php and saw the function

```
update_do_once($module, $version, &$context);
```

I can't say I understand what `$context` is, and I can't get this working even after doing a full bootstrap. I get no errors, just nothing happens.

Has anyone every done this before?

Comment: I did realize I could just include the .install file of the module and execute the hook_update_N functions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_update_N/6).

Answer (score 0):

This might now be what you were aming for with your question, but an excellent programming tool for Drupal is [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

On your terminal you only need to run

```
 $ drush updb
```

to update modules.

Comment: I should have noted that this is for a test fixture that tests a custom module that I wrote. I don't think Drush will work for that will it? It will try to get it from drupal.org, which it won't find, right? And what if I only want to make certain I am updating a particular module, not all available updates for every module.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can run my own [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_update_N/6) functions apart from update.php, as long as I am bootstrapped and include the module's .install file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be straight forward in both Drupal 6 & 7:

```
$sandbox = array();
module_load_include('install', 'foo');
foo_update_7001($sandbox);
```